# Why doesn't the USA use drones and bombardment to support the Afghan government troops?

Tags: united-states, military, afghanistan, taliban

Since 2001, it was the usual practice. Various warlords and the government army fight on the field, and they get air support from the USA military.

[Sometimes Taliban leaders were also killed by USA drones.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akhtar_Mansour)

While the USA left Afghanistan, it does not mean that they should not give air support to the government.

However, this time, there is nothing about it in the news. Why?

Comment: Which news have you been following? What I have been reading time and time again is that they are actually still providing air support (albeit without benefit of US military personnel on the ground for precise targeting) but that it is likely to end at the end of the month.

Comment: This Q. seems to be based on an incorrect premise that *"the news"* is somehow able to provide a complete real-time report of US air strikes.  On the contrary, [*"No one who isn’t legally compelled to keep quiet knows the full extent of the extrajudicial executions that the federal government has carried out over the past four years, or the number of innocents who died in the process."*](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2021/01/americas-shadow-death-row/617757/)

Comment: The U.S. did for 20 years. Within days of them ceasing to do so, Kabul fell. It takes U.S. troops (and lots of $$) to run high end drones and close air support. The ANA has a few glorified Cessnas with helicopter type missiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Because you cannot substitute motivated and confident infantry with air strikes.**

That's like situation in Yemen, where Saudis are dominating in air, but cannot prevent houthi's ground advances - just because they don't have good, confident infantry, only mercenaries.

Also you should notice, that each Afghan's government forces defeat lowers morale of other their troops. In fact, the only really confident power staying in Ghani's hand are "commando" forces, trained by the US troops - but it's not infantry, it's something like special operation forces - which are too small and too lightly armed to change anything.

If the enemy moves secretly, with infantry columns, and in a rough landscape - aviation can do nearly nothing. And after closing the distance, ground forces are on their own, because air strikes always have "safety distance" - about 500 meters, depending on landscape. If your troops are in close combat - you won't help them with your air forces.

So, you have Taliban advancing in many provinces, in a rough landscape. Air strikes won't help here - only **your** ground forces, which are nearly out.
If nothing changes, Taliban main gain control over the country till the end of the month.

**PS**

One of the few situations, where US air strikes really stopped advancing was
[Pusan's perimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Pusan_Perimeter). There NK army was stopped by *constant* US air strikes and strikes of naval artillery. But that was only *perimeter*, for a short time, but not the whole country.

**PS 2**

About "regular and hard bombardment of the enemy":

- you should first *spot* it. In mountains all over the country.
- you should have **huge** amount of bombers.

Since Pakistan rejected US request for air bases, only Katar bases and US carriers are available. Katar air base is useful only for B-52 - others are out of range. US have totally 58 B-52. If all of them would go in charge, yes, situation may change. But that's not many - remember about refueling, pilots rest and supplying.

Comment: I have the impression, that a regular and hard bombardment of the enemy significantly improves also the morale of the friendly side.

Comment: I'll update my answer with more details, @GraySheep